# Does ASP.NET with AJAX work on iOS (Safari, Chrome, etc.)?

Tags: .net, ajax

If so, what are the limitations?  More specifically can I access local resources to do file I/O to something like C:\SomeApp  (non "Protected" paths)?

I'm currently using more robust (aka powerful) technologies like Silverlight 5 to work very complex UI's to give our users a "stand-alone" application like feel (Out-of-Browser) but single web deployment (instant updates).

I know Silverlight got killed of by Apple (Microsoft caved in) in 2011 and will be permanently blocked by 2021.  BUT, I'm having a hard time finding any web front end technology to replace Silverlight, as in none as powerful and as user friendly.  Hence the desire to shift to ASP.NET with AJAX as that might be the least time consuming to move the SL UI over ... but my concern is can ASP.NET with AJAX handle the UI complexity.

I've looked at Xamarin as a possible alternative but even if the code did work correctly (unmodified) across several platforms, it's still 3 or 4 deployment builds.  And it's my understanding each platform compile may have restrictions and hence code adjustments made for each specific OS platform deployment.

Thoughts?

Cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build application for mobile device and write busuness logic on .NET but don't want to create UI for each platform you should look at Xamarin Forms. If you familiar with Javascript you can use Flutter or Ionic frameworks. ASP.NET is web server technology.

Comment: I should probably clarify and/or narrow my questions (actually more than one).

Comment: Ugh, 5 minute limit to my edits at StackOverflow???  Oye, that's nuts.  Anyway ... I was hoping to stay with single deployment on a web server rather than do 3 deployments using Xamarin Forms for iOS, Android, Windows.  The problem is that web centric apps are very limited in how complex they can be and restricted on file I/O access (i.e. user input is REQUIRED in order to allow File I/O operations).